# Como buscar pelo registro quando a tabela tem chave primária composta?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-sql

Tenho no meu banco de dados a tabela `t_command_control`.

Esta tabela tem uma chave primária composta formadas pelos campos `CD_STATION` e `CD_COMMAND`.

Se a chave primária fosse simples (apenas como campo `CD_STATION`) eu usaria a expressão abaixo para selecionar o registro que eu preciso.

```
Entities db = new Entities();
t_command_control objCommandControl = db.t_command_control.FirstOrDefault(e => e.CD_STATION == itCdStation);
```

Porém sendo a chave primária composta não sei como selecionar.

Answer (score 2):

As expressões lambda podem possuir mais de uma expressão booleana. No seu caso, é só utilizar o operador condicional `E` (`&&`), deixando a expressão da seguinte forma:

```
Entities db = new Entities();

t_command_control objCommandControl = db.t_command_control.FirstOrDefault(e => e.CD_STATION == itCdStation && e.CD_COMMAND == itCdCommand);
```